# phpcbf doesn't see installed phpcs standard

Tags: php, wordpress, phpcs

I’ve installed the [WordPress Coding Standards](https://github.com/WordPress-Coding-Standards/WordPress-Coding-Standards) for `phpcs`. Running `phpcs -i` confirms this:

```
The installed coding standards are MySource, PEAR, PHPCS, 
PSR1, PSR2, Squiz, Zend, WordPress, WordPress-Core, 
WordPress-Docs, WordPress-Extra and WordPress-VIP
```

However, running `phpcbf -i` it would seem that `phpcbf` doesn't see these:

```
The installed coding standards are MySource, PEAR, PSR1, 
PSR2, Squiz and Zend
```

Trying to run the `--config_set installed_paths` that I used on `phpcs` on `phpcbf` results in errors upon running `phpcbf`.

How can I get `phpcbf` to use the WordPress Coding Standards I’ve installed for `phpcs`?

I’m on macOS Sierra 10.12.5

Comment: phpcs and phpcbf use the exact same code base, so the list of installed standards should be identical (it's the same method that runs to print the list for both). I just tested this on Sierra and it's working fine for me. Is there any chance these commands are pointing at different code bases? If you run `which phpcs` and `which phpcbf` do the files exist in the same location? How was PHP_CodeSniffer installed (PEAR, Composer, Git clone)?

Comment: @GregSherwood was spot on - the two commands were symlinks pointing at different installs. Not sure what the correct protocol is here - do you want to post this as an answer?

Comment: Maybe just post a solution describing how you figured that out and how you fixed it so someone else can find a solution next time. I didn't do much more than ask a few questions here, but I'm glad you managed to figure out the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Greg Sherwood’s comment above pointed me in the right direction. The two commands were symlinks pointing at different installs. I figured this out by running 
`which phpcs` and `which phpcbf` and running `readlink` (to see if they were symlinks) on the results.

`which phpcs` gave me `/usr/local/bin/phpcs` and `readlink /usr/local/bin/phpcs` gave me the path to the actual executable.

Once I figured out that `phpcbf` was a symlink to an executable in a different install I deleted it and replaced it with a symlink to `phpcbf` in the same install as `phpcs`, which solved my issue.